# kubernetes service isn't starting

Tags: json, linux, kubernetes, yaml

I'm trying to start a service I added to kubernetes and I'm not sure why it isn't starting.  I'm able to add it with

```
d2 swarm service add 'testservice/daemonset.yaml'
```

then when I start it I see

```
d2 swarm service add 'testservice/daemonset.yaml'
creating service
```

and now when I ssh into the swarm and do

```
kubectl get ds -n testing
```

It shows up as a service but not as started

Is there any other logs or debug services commands I can use?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get ds` gives you current status of the [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/), but to see why its Pods (or rather, container(s) in these pods) aren't running you'll have to describe the pods, not the DaemonSet.

1. Run `kubectl get pods -n testing` to get a list of pods. Since this is a DaemonSet, there should be one pod per worker node. The `STATUS` column tells you which state the pod is currently in. Ideally it should say `Running`.
2. If `STATUS` is not `Running`, grab the pod `NAME` and run `kubectl describe pod <pod_name> -n testing`. Look for the `Events` section towards the bottom; It normally tells you what's wrong with your pod.
3. If the log says it's trying to restart a failed container, that means the service itself is most likely crashing. You can check the logs from the service by running `kubectl logs <pod_name> -n testing`.

This is typically enough to troubleshoot service-related issues preventing pods from starting up. If you still cannot figure out what the problem is, please update your question with output from each of these steps (after omitting personal/sensitive information, of course) so we can help you further.

Comment: thanks it turns out my pod must not have been created or added properly as it doesn't show up in the get pods command